# Video Autodelete in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, video

I have job portal website in Wordpress
Now I want to add a feature for applicants / candidates where they can record a video, replay the same but it will not store anywhere in the website's database.

How can I achieve this feature into my website, please help...

I searched for the 3rd party but I did not get a proper solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate a third-party video recording and playback service.there is services available that allow you to achieve this functionality without the need to handle video storage on your website.

**Documentation** :https://webplatform.github.io/docs/concepts/Internet_and_Web/webrtc/

**Also you can use this plugin** -
https://wordpress.org/plugins/videowhisper-live-streaming-integration